# Solve for $y$ explicitly or prove that it is impossible

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say you want to solve for $y$ explicitly (it is by itself on one side of the equation with no $y$'s on the other side) in terms of any sort of function (elementary or non-elementary) in the following equation:

$$\sin(y)+e^y-xy=0$$

> Is this possible? Or, if it isn't, *prove* that it is impossible.

**Edit:** After seeing an answer, I am providing another example:
$$\sin(xy)-\frac xye^y=0$$

This is a very "over the top" example, but my question is the same.

**Edit #2:** After seeing jgon's answer (thank you), I was wondering:

> Is there any way to prove that these are impossible to solve explicitly for $y$ without using graphs?

Comment: $y = f^{-1}(x)$ where $f(y) = \frac{e^y + \sin y}{y}$. Does that count?

Comment: Are you asking for a solution for $y$ using only elementary functions? And would the relation not being one-to-one be enough proof for your statement? You need more make your question more clear.

Comment: @uranix $f$ is not injective.

Comment: @RoryDaulton All I am asking for is to solve for $y$ explicitly, to me it doesn't matter how you do it! :)

Comment: @Tdonot What is the purpose of your question?

Comment: @Tdonut what Rory Daulton said is that *it matters*.

Comment: By the way, [see your last question for yourself](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28xy%29-x%2Fye^y%3D0)

Comment: @mvw I have encountered some questions involving equations like this, but they were always deemed as "you have to use a calculator". I am curious!

Comment: @Tdonut Is $\sin x = a$ solved explicitly by your definition by $x = \arcsin a$?

Comment: @uranix Yes it is.

Comment: So than there is no such thing as explicit solution to an equation. You are always able to introduce a new function and say that it is defined as a soltion to that equation. Just like $\arcsin a$ is introduced as a solution to $\sin x = a$ from $x \in [0, 2\pi]$. Another example $x e^x = y$ has an "explicit" solution $x = \operatorname{LambertW}(y)$ which definition is exactly the equation. Even $x = \frac{1}{y}$ is defined as a solution to $x y = 1$. Inverse functions are natural, they just don't always have a closed form.

Answer (score 6):

It is impossible. We can solve for $x$, and then graph $x$ as a function of $y$. $x=\frac{\sin(y)+e^y}{y}$. (See below, $y$ is on the horizontal axis, and $x$ is on the vertical axis)

Since there are two values for $y$ that give $x=10$, $y$ is not a function of $x$, or how could we pick what value to assign $y$ when $x=10$?

Therefore we cannot solve for $y$, since solving for $y$ expresses $y$ as a function of $x$.

[image: graph of $x$ as a function of $y$]

### Edit

To answer your second question, Wolfram Alpha can graph implicit functions like this. The picture we get this time is the following:

[image]

This is a really interesting curve, but this time, it is neither a function of $x$ nor $y$ for the same reasons as above, so we cannot solve the equation for either $x$ or $y$.

### Edit 2

In general to show that a curve defined implicitly in terms of $x$ and $y$ cannot be solved for one of the variables say $y$, what you need to do is find two points on the curve where the value of $x$ is the same, but the points differ at their $y$ coordinate. See the first part of my answer, there were two points on the curve with $x=10$, and different $y$ coordinates. Then if you had $y=f(x)$, then how would you know what $f(10)$ is?

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I am going to add to my question.

Comment: @Tdonut added response to new question

Comment: Thank you, this cleared things up.

Comment: @Tdonut no problem!

Comment: I added more to my question, but please don't delete your answer! It is good.

Comment: Am  I the only one who went "woahh, dude..." when I saw that bottom graph?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to prove that these are impossible to solve explicitly for $y$ without using graphs?

The [implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) gives conditions for the existence of a (in general local defined) function $y = f(x)$ which satisfies $0 = F(x, f(x))$. If they do not hold, it is not possible.

The problem of expressing a solution with elementary functions starts already with the problem what an elementary function is ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function)).

A famous theorem about non-expressiveness in terms of elementary functions is Liouville's theorem about antiderivatives ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29), [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm)).

Answer (score 0):

1.)

By looking for algebraic values of terms in the given equation, one finds at first e.g. the following solutions.

$\sin(y)+e^y-xy=0:$ $x=\frac{e^{k\pi}}{k\pi}$, $y=k\pi$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

$\sin(y)+e^y-xy=0:$ $x\in \{-\frac{k\pi}{2W(-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt\frac{k\pi}{sin(k\pi)})},-\frac{k\pi}{2W(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt\frac{k\pi}{sin(k\pi)})}\}$, $y=\frac{k\pi}{x}$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, $W$: Lambert W function

$$ $$

2.)

Interpret your zeroing equation as $H(x,y)=0$, $F(x)=0$ and $G(y)=0$. You have to try to find the global or local inverses of the functions $H$, $F$ or $G$. If it is not possible to find an inverse by only simplifying the left-hand sides of this equations, it is not possible to solve the equation in closed form on this way.

2a)

The possibility of an elementary inverse of an elementary function is treated in [Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/).

Your equations don't have a structure for which a non-constant elementary function as solution exist.

2b)

There are no commonly used Special functions like Lambert W function as inverses of $H$, $F$ or $G$.

$$ $$

3.)

The posiibilitiy of solvability of equations by elementary functions or by Liouvillian functions is treated in:

[Liouville, J.: Mémoire sur la classification des transcendantes, et sur l’impossibilité d’exprimer les racines de certaines équations en fonction finie explicite des coefficients. Journ. Math. pures et appl. 2 (1837) 56-105](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/feuilleter.php?id=JMPA_1837_1_2)

[Liouville, J.: Suite du Mémoire sur la classification des transcendantes, et sur l'impossibilité d'exprimer les racines de certaines équations en fonction finie explicite des coefficients. Journal de mathématiques pures et appliquées 3 (1838) 523-547](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/feuilleter.php?id=JMPA_1838_1_3)

$$ $$

4.)

The question of solvability of equations by functions from a differential field (e.g. by elementary functions or by Liouvillian functions) is treated in [Rosenlicht, M.: On the explicit solvability of certain transcendental equations. Publications mathématiques de l'IHÉS 36 (1969) 15-22](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1969__36__15_0).

An explanation of such function classes is given e.g. in section 1 of [Davenport, J. H.: What Might "Understand a Function" Mean. In: Kauers, M.; Kerber, M., Miner, R.;  Windsteiger, W.: Towards Mechanized Mathematical Assistants. Springer, Berlin/Heidelberg, 2007, page 55-65](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/What-Might-Understand-a-Function-Mean-Davenport/3b2f16e35f86d53bc75429e8431e0a453e9af3e4).

$$ $$

See Wikipedia for the corresponding mathematical technical terms.